# Formatting text and adding text-part between specific pattern

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, text-processing

On GNU/Linux, I've following output by running `ls` command:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  4 18:21 Documents+Edu -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  4 18:17 Ext4 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  4 18:21 Game+Movie -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  4 18:42 OS -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar  4 18:20 Software+Video -> ../../sda5
```

And I want the following output:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media/$USER/Documents+Edu
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/$USER/Ext4
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /media/$USER/Game+Movie
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /media/$USER/OS
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /media/$USER/Software+Video
```

In other words:-

- Adding text `sudo mount /dev/` before every `/sdax` and `/media/$USER/` before labels like: `Documents+Edu` etc.
- Formatting as needed.

How can I achieve desired output on Linux by using commands like: `grep`, `cut`, `awk`, `sed`, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option could be to avoid `ls` altogether iterating through the files with `readlink`:

```
$ cat ../nols.sh
cd /dev/disk/by-label
for f in *
do
    v=$(basename $(readlink $f))
    echo "sudo mount /dev/$v /media/\$USER/$f"
done


$ sh ../nols.sh
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media/$USER/Documents+Edu
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/$USER/Ext4
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /media/$USER/Game+Movie
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /media/$USER/OS
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /media/$USER/Software+Video
```

Comment: This is working but it is necessary that `for f in *` should be executed under `/dev/disk/by-label` to get desired output. So, add `cd /dev/disk/by-label` before `for f in *` and I will accept.

Comment: However this seems not text-processing, but Thank-you for suggesting `readlink` and `basename`!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need anything apart from the names and its symbolic links, it might me best to just do `ls -1` (one instead of `L`) ot just get the last column. Then, pipe to this `awk`:

```
awk -F"->|/" '{printf "sudo mount /dev/%s /media/$USER/%s\n", $NF, $1}'
```

It slices the text in either `->` or `/` separators. Based on that, it gets the last one and the first one and populates the string accordingly.

#### Test

```
$ ls -1 /dev/disk/by-label/ | awk -F"->|/" '{printf "sudo mount /dev/%s /media/$USER/%s\n", $NF, $1}'
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media/$USER/Documents+Edu 
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/$USER/Ext4 
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /media/$USER/Game+Movie 
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /media/$USER/OS 
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /media/$USER/Software+Video
```

Comment: on my system (test on AIX and linux RHEL), `ls -1` does not return the pointed file, just the logical file name, different on yours ?

Comment: You are right! I just checked `man ls` and I cannot find the way to just show this `file -> target`, uhms...

Comment: The command `ls -1 /dev/disk/by-label/ | awk -F"->|/" '{printf "sudo mount /dev/%s /media/$USER/%s\n", $NF, $1}'`  outputs [this](http://pastebin.com/e8Rut1nm). (`/dev/<label>` instead of `/dev/<sdaz>`)

Answer (score 0):

```
# -- Prepare ---
Folder='/dev/disk/by-label/'
HeaderLen=$(ls -ld . | wc -c )

# -- execute ---
ls -l "${Folder}" | sed "1d;s#.\{${HeaderLen}\}\(.*\) -> .*\(/[^/]*\)#sudo mount /dev\2 /media/\$USER/\1#;t;d"
```

- estimate the first partof ls that is not used (and will be removed)
- list the folder pipe to a sed
- remove 1st line (total info)
- remove first part and take 2 group of text separate by `->`, rewrtie it in new format
- if substitution occur, go to end of script (print)
- if no, remove the line (and cycle without print). This remove file not linked in your format